# When (or after) uploading a video, how to set its privacy?

Tags: facebook, video, upload, privacy, audience

We have an Apple iOS application which uploads video to Facebook. One the corresponding Facebook app side, we have asked our users to set it's privacy to public, to encourage sharing.

It has been working fine until around two weeks ago, the uploaded video can only be seen by friends only, if the user has set the default privacy to friends. It says:

> "Control Your Default Privacy This setting will apply to status
>   updates and photos you post to your profile from a Facebook app that
>   doesn't have the inline audience selector, like Facebook for
>   Blackberry."

I checked the Facebook graph API doc and did quite some search, and couldn't find a way to set the privacy setting of the video.

Comment: Looking for the same information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your application to share things to public by default. However, the user's own privacy settings will be taken into account over the application permissions. So, if the user's maximum privacy level is set to `friends`, your application will only be able to share to friends, unless the user manually changes their privacy settings.